# Texture painting go weird

Tags: uv, texture-painting, resolution

I have modeling and sculpting 2 difference object in this project. As in the picture there is a turtle shell and turtle body. I can paint texture normally fine with the turtle shell which has lower polygon as in the second picture.

[image]

[image]

But for the body my computer got frozen and the program has been shutdown afterward. I think it might need too much memory than my computer can proceed. So I tried to lower the polygon resolution by using decimate modifier and it work. Now I can paint on the turtle body.

But after I paint on an object. Painting color painted on an object flew along all the object like a water color and it is uncontrollable. As in the picture, one simple click on an object made a color flow along the object like a weird strip. Not like a normal brush painting.

[image]

I tried with another object with quite high polygon resolution. Without decimate modifier function added. But the texture painting got the same problem. I'm using 2.92 Blender version. I also noticed that there is no UV unwrap showing in texture paint UVs tab. Does anyone know how to fix this problem ? I'm so desperate now since I tried to search through both Youtube and blogs but there are nothing close to what I'm looking for. I aprreciated to any help in advance.

[image]

Comment: If it doesn't paint correctly it's probably because the UV is not correct, you should unwrap again (with Smart UV Project mode for example). In order to see the UV in the Image Editor / Paint mode, select all the object's vertices in Edit mode.

Comment: @moonboots they actually don't have a problem with the UV, but rather how the surface is getting painted, which is getting painted like water colours, spilling out everywhere.

Comment: maybe he should share his object so that we can test: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The UV are messed up since you decimated the mesh - don't paint until you are done with your modeling/sculpting and then have worked out your ideal mesh topology, preferably using retopology to get a better 'all quads' mesh that you can rig and animate. Then you can get a better UV scheme and paint with better performance and predictable results.

Comment: Thank you guys for sharing solutions. I'm so new to Blender and sculpting software. So it took me so long to learn about retopology, uv unwrapping and it's method. But good luck that the smart uv projection is working with this case. Now I can paint on an object in 3D view without the water color spilling effect. And don't have to do retopolygy to all models in this project because that's would be lots lots of time. I appreciated all of you from my heart to have take a look on my problem. You all are my saviors!